# se puede poner un scriollvieww a un tabs estoy tratando de poner pero no baja este es mi codigo

Tags: android

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".View.RegistroMenu1"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Registro de Restaurantes"
    android:textColor="#111111"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/nombre"
                        android:layout_width="282dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_store_black_24dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="nombre"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/direccion"
                    android:layout_width="282dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_directions_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Direccion"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/telefono"
                    android:layout_width="282dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_phone_black_24dp"

                    android:hint="Telefono"
                    android:inputType="number" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/categoria"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/horarios"
                android:layout_width="282dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Seleccione Horario"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/selectlugar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Mi Ubicación "
                android:textColor="#111111" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/idimagen"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_base"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createRes"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="btnUpload_Click"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Registrar"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/foto"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="btnUpload_Click"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Registrar"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
                <Button

                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:onClick="ENVIAR"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="Registrar"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Fragmento

ACTIVIDAD QUE CONTIENE ETIQUETAS DEL TAB

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu Marino" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu Criollo " />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItem3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Menu Oriental" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Actividad del fragmento
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menucriollo, container, false);

```
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el "tab"? , no veo ninguno en tu layout.

Comment: ese es un frgmento que contiene mis etiquetas aqui esta el codigo del tap

Comment: ya lo actualize